# game unit collision with obstacle

Tags: collision-detection, chipmunk

I am making an action game and is **trying to make the player character not being able to pass through obstacles** in the game map. Situation is similar to the game Metal Gear obstacles(wall) in the middle of the scene.

[image]

Because movement are controlled by player so its not a path-finding problem.
I am considering to use a physics library (e.g. chipmunk) to detect the collision between the unit (sphere) and any obstacle (arbitrary polygon).
When collision occurs, i can just restore to prev position. 
The potential problem is, if the movement speed is high in the game, restoring to the prev position may place the character not close enough to the obstacle/wall (e.g.empty space between unit and wall).

Questions:

1.Is there any other better implementation method?

2.I am not sure if I can use the Physics lib this way as the unit Sphere is moved manually by hand based on user input (constant speed) instead of using force. I prefer not to use force because some unit's movement is handled by server which do not run any physics engine. Its could be difficult to sync the movement speed when client side use force and server side use movement speed for movement.

Thanks